# XCode cannot find auto-generated swift header moduleName-Swift.h in pch file in duplicate target

Tags: ios, xcode, duplicates, target, pch

I duplicated a target and get the following build error:

```
Resource/Prefix.pch:16:13: '<moduleName>-Swift.h' file not found
```

I can't see any difference between the two targets that would cause this problem.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the duplicate target has a different `moduleName`.

I had to add a C-flag in the duplicate target and use this in `Prefix.pch`. (A User-Defined Setting doesn't get seen when parsing the pch file.)

[image]

```
#ifdef DEVLOPMENT_SERVER
    #import "<duplicateModuleName>-Swift.h"
#else
    #import "<moduleName>-Swift.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You change the value `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME` ('Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name') in Build Settings so that you have the same header file name for both targets.